# Running Setup.exe created by Inno Setup and get "... '"isxdl.dll' was not found." error

Tags: inno-setup, istool

Compiled a Inno Setup script (IS v5.4.2), but when ran resulting Setup.exe, an error dialog appeared with content:
    Internal error: ExtractTemporaryFile: The file "isxdl.dll" was not found.

I could not find this .DLL anywhere on my system.  While there's probably a good technical reason for it, I found it confusing that the Inno Setup compiler did not complain that the ISXDL.DLL was not available.

=============================
****Found Answer Myself ****

I found the issue myself after a bit of searching and experimentation.  Evidently I had at one point installed "ISTool", which contains the ISXDL.DLL file, and used "ISTool" to construct and/or compile the .ISS script in question.  This placed some references like the following in the setup.

```
procedure isxdl_AddFile(URL, Filename: AnsiString);
external 'isxdl_AddFile@files:isxdl.dll stdcall';
function isxdl_DownloadFiles(hWnd: Integer): Integer;
external 'isxdl_DownloadFiles@files:isxdl.dll stdcall';
function isxdl_SetOption(Option, Value: AnsiString): Integer;
external 'isxdl_SetOption@files:isxdl.dll stdcall';
```

For whatever reason, I uninstalled ISTool (possibly motivated by fact that ISTool is not listed, as of May 20, 2011, on the Inno Setup [3rd Party Tools](http://www.jrsoftware.org/is3rdparty.php) page), but this left the related code still in my script, which compiled okay using Inno Setup.

Comment: Please add the answer to the question and accept it.

Comment: I think Robert meant you should add your answer *as an answer* to this question, not actually adding the answer to the question text. That way we could vote on it and you can accept it.

Comment: I tried to do what you both suggested, but since I was a new user, I was prevented from doing so for an 8 hour lock-out period.  So not wanting to waste others time possibly searching for an answer that did not exist, I did the next best thing and edit the "Question" area.  I know, not the correct procedure, but the only avenue open to me at the time.  I will follow your suggestions and provide my answer myself.

Comment: Do you think I should, now that I have "Answered" my own question, remove the "answer" from the "Question", or would that just confuse people all the more?

Comment: Yes, removing the answer from the question text would be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I found the issue myself after a bit of searching and experimentation.  Evidently I had at one point (i.e., a year or more ago) installed "ISTool", which contains the ISXDL.DLL file, and used "ISTool" to construct and/or compile the .ISS script in question.  This placed some references like the following in the .ISS setup script.

```
procedure isxdl_AddFile(URL, Filename: AnsiString);
external 'isxdl_AddFile@files:isxdl.dll stdcall';
function isxdl_DownloadFiles(hWnd: Integer): Integer;
external 'isxdl_DownloadFiles@files:isxdl.dll stdcall';
function isxdl_SetOption(Option, Value: AnsiString): Integer;
external 'isxdl_SetOption@files:isxdl.dll stdcall';
```

For whatever reason, I uninstalled ISTool (possibly motivated by fact that ISTool is not listed, as of May 20, 2011, on the Inno Setup [3rd Party Tools](http://www.jrsoftware.org/is3rdparty.php) page), but this left the related code still in my script, which subsequently compiled okay using "Inno Setup".

To correct this, I just deleted the code containing the references to "_isxdl".

Answer (score 2):

You need to have ISXDL.DLL listed in your `[Files]` section to use the listed functions.

The source code to ISXDL.DLL can be found on the the [Project Page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/istool/).